# Indicator and Hazard Sometimes Not Working

Tags: nissan, indicators, x-trail

Hey guys hope you are all doing well.
I have Nissan X Trail 2006, I am facing an issue with my car, Indicator(Turn Signal) and hazard light sometimes stop working during drive(nothing come on dashboard) and after sometime it starts to work fine.
I thought may be indicator fuse is at fault.
But I checked all the fuses and all are okay.
Any idea what is the issue, this happened after I didn't start my car for 43 days, the battery was dead.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! When you flip the indicator switch, either way, or for hazards, nothing happens?

Comment: Indicator and hazard work fine but sometimes randomly it stop working, when a flip the switch and press hazard button nothing happens, after a while it start working normally.

Comment: When it stops working, no indicators are showing (i.e. green turn signal indicator on the dash goes dark)?

Comment: Yes no Indicator turn signal is showing in dash, same when I press Hazard button.

Comment: Somebody suggested me when next time this issue happens remove Battery Terminal for few mins to reset electronics.